# Trying to save everything in R environment to disk

Tags: r, caching, save

I need to save items in my environment in R to disk. I can't figure out why the following code doesn't work :

```
op <- function(){
    for(i in 1:length(ls())){
        file <- paste0(ls()[i],".Rds")
        saveRDS(file,file)
    }
}
```

Comment: `file` is a string (that includes the `".Rds"` you pasted on the end of it), so you're telling `saveRDS` to save the string stored in `file` (not the object of that name minus the .Rds part).

Comment: Would be nice to have a real answer since comments are ephemeral...

Comment: I invite anyone to expand on my comment and turn it into a full answer. I have no plans to delete my comment and I doubt a moderator would either, so I don't think it's very ephemeral. (Nor is it a good answer as-is, which is why I left a quick, helpful comment rather than a short, crummy answer.)

Answer (score 5):

There are actually couple things wrong here:

1. I suspect you want to save `.GlobalEnv`, not just `op`'s environment. However the calls to `ls` will list objects in `op`'s environment (which is only `i` by the time you call `ls`). If you want to list object in `.GlobalEnv`, call `ls(.GlobalEnv)`
2. Also, when you are calling `saveRDS`, you are telling it to save a string stored in `file` into path stored in file. So you are essentially only saving the path. Instead you need to get the object from `.GlobalEnv`

So one of correct ways to do it would be:

```
op <- function(){
    obj_names <- ls(.GlobalEnv)
    for(i in 1:length(obj_names){
        file <- paste0(obj_names[i],".Rds")
        saveRDS(get(obj_names[i], envir = .GlobalEnv), file)
    }
}
```

Or a bit more idiomatic,

```
op <- function()
    sapply(ls(.GlobalEnv), function(x) saveRDS(get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv), paste0(x, ".Rds"))
```

Also `save` function might be useful, if you don't mind saving all objects in one file. More at `?save`

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote only saves a list of files with names identical to the names in the environment of your function (i.e. a single file "i.rds").

If you want to save the contents of an environment to a file, you might want to try the `save()` or `save.image()` function which does exactly what you are looking for.

For information try `?save`. Here is some code:

```
   a <- 1
   b <- 2
   save(list=ls(), file="myfile.rda")
   rm(list=ls())
   load(file="myfile.rda")
   ls()
```

yielding:

```
 [1] "a" "b"
```